# Cannot run openCV sample FaceDetection Application

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I have Downloaded the openCV library. Now when I m trying to run the sample faceDetection application it shows the following error :

```
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load detection_based_tracer: findLibrary returned null

 08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):    at com.kratin.opencvfacedetection.FdActivity$1.onManagerConnected(FdActivity.java:36)
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:206)
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1064)
 08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1081)
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
 08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
 08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
 08-11 15:59:55.071: E/AndroidRuntime(13837):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But the precompiled facedetection.apk runs without any problem. so whats going wrong when I am running it from sample application?? Pls help me out..I am using ubuntu os.

Answer (score 0):

Solved..I have set the environment variable path to ndk..and made link using ln command and the problem solved after rebuild..

Comment: I suggest elaborating a little on the steps you did (cause this question has been asked again and again) and also accept your answer.

Comment: @Rekha, Could please note down steps if possible as you solved the issue?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you use ubuntu,

project Right Click -> properties -> c/c++ build -> Build command

If this is ndk-build.cmd , you must fix " your ndk path/ndk-build "