# Face Detection OpenCV4Android doesn't work

Tags: android, opencv, logcat, face-detection

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

I used this tutorial exactly to install OpenCV on my Eclipse and Android, everything is working fine except:

- Unfortunately, OCV Face Detection has stopped.
- Unfortunately, OCV Native Activity has stopped.
- Unfortunately, OCV Mixed Processing has stopped.

I only need the face detection one, (for now at least).

I did a through research on this problem this problem has been asked ALOT and couldn't find a complete, working solution or any decent answer. It would be beneficial for the whole community if have a complete answer. Here are some information:

- I do not have C/C++ Build tab on my project properties so I thought it wasn't needed.
- I didn't bother with running it on the emulator.
- OpenCV Manager is downloaded from Google Play
- Java 1.6
- Android 4.3, API 18
- Device model is Nexus 10

Here is the logcat:

```
11-20 16:44:15.389: I/OCVSample::Activity(27418): OpenCV loaded successfully
11-20 16:44:15.389: D/AndroidRuntime(27418): Shutting down VM
11-20 16:44:15.389: W/dalvikvm(27418): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415dc700)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load detection_based_tracker from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:355)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:525)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity$1.onManagerConnected(FdActivity.java:66)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1106)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1123)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 16:44:15.399: E/AndroidRuntime(27418):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913900/cannot-run-opencv-sample-facedetection-application?rq=1

Comment: You need to compile the JNI first.

Comment: @Mahm00d I've checked. Have you checked it yourself? It's useless.

Comment: @MidnightGuest, Well, the linked question has an answer (albeit vague). I wish the OP of that question explained the solution steps. But I agree, at this condition, it's close to useless. It's just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Android Studio, tried all other answers, finally copying the libdetection_based_tracker.so file 
from OpenCV-android-sdk/samples/face_detection/libs/armeabi-v7a 
into myProject/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-7a , solved my problem.